# Erro ao enviar arquivo através do método PostAsJsonAsync no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

No meu `Controller` de um projeto `Asp.net MVC` eu recebo da `View` uma imagem do tipo `HttpPostedFileBase` e preciso enviar ao `Web Api` utilizando `PostAsJsonAsync`:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/image", image);
```

A imagem está vindo normalmente, mas ao chegar na linha acima aparece esse erro:

`"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'."`

Obs.: mandar "image.InputStream" da o mesmo erro.

Como resolver esse problema? Obrigado.

Update: o Web Api implementei com base nessa resposta: [Como salvar e retornar imagens com Web Api?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19454/como-salvar-e-retornar-imagens-com-web-api/19461#19461)

Comment: Se tem o código, ou seja, os métodos? que possa postar?

Comment: Voce não tem que usar image.InputStream?

Comment: @f.fujihara Tentei mandar o image.InputStream e dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: o metodo que recebe e enviar para o webapi (os dois se possivel)

Comment: @HarryPotter fiz a com base nessa resposta, mas não testei ainda pq estou com esse problema que impede a imagem de chegar lá: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19461/8356

Comment: O que você quer fazer com a imagem?

Comment: @f.fujihara tenho um projeto asp.net mvc que no controller recebe essa imagem da View e quero enviar para um outro projeto Web Api. Nesse projeto quero receber a imagem e salvar em um diretório. Resumindo: salvar a imagem e poder retornar ela, usando o Asp.net MVC junto Web Api(projetos separados que estão em uma mesma solution). O que estou tentando fazer é isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19454/como-salvar-e-retornar-imagens-com-web-api

Comment: Voce recebe na Controller um parametro do tipo HttpPostedFileBase, e se na Business voce recebesse um parametro do tipo Stream? (image.InputStream). Ficaria mais fácil para voce manipular e enviar a outro diretório.

Comment: Bom eu postei um exemplo de como eu faria, espero que ajude, @CarlosGeovanio

Comment: @HarryPotter vou testar essa tua resposta, muito Obrigado.

Comment: OK @CarlosGeovanio

Comment: Deu certo @CarlosGeovanio ?

Comment: deu sim @HarryPotter. Muito obrigado.

Comment: se puder fecha a questão para servir de modelo para os demais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Exemplo:***

*Essa classe servirá de base para o transporte da imagem com o seu nome e o array de bytes.*

```
public class Transporte
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
}
```

***Métodos da Action (Web MVC)***

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EnviarImagem()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public void EnviarImagem(HttpPostedFileBase imagem)
{
    int tam = (int)imagem.InputStream.Length;
    byte[] imgByte = new byte[tam];
    imagem.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, tam);

    HttpClient web = new HttpClient();
    web.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:17527/");
    HttpResponseMessage response = web.PostAsJsonAsync("api/GravarImagem", new Transporte() { Imagem = imgByte, Name = imagem.FileName }).Result;            
}
```

***View referente as esses métodos***

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EnviarImagem</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <form method="post" action="/Home/EnviarImagem" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" />
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Web Api***

```
public class RecebeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/GravarImagem")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GravarImagem(Transporte transporte)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/") + transporte.Name, transporte.Imagem);
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }
}
```

***Debug:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]